# Does one still require an IOC to use Fluent Security?

Tags: fluent-security

Is it possible to run Fluent Security without IOC? My application does not currently use IOC, hence the reason for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, FluentSecurity does not require an IoC-container (it never has).
However, if you need to replace anything in FluentSecurity or if you need dependency injection for your policies, you need a way to provide FluentSecurity with those instances/dependencies.